# Please help identify this font - Have tried all font identifier programs

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image: Unidentified Font in Use]

Font used here is close to Goudy Trajan or Galba MN and a few others, but when I look closer at all options, they are not quite the same. The next best guess is Trajan Pro 3 Semi-bold, but I'm not entirely sure about that, either.

I optimized the image according to instructions given on sites like WhatTheFont and Identifont and submitted for identification. I have tried all of the identification programs suggested here, so far, but no cigar. Maybe I'm missing something.

It seems pretty difficult to determine the exact font in this case because I don't have more than a few words to work with - limited characters - and they are all in caps, no lower case to use for reference. Can't use The Serif Identification Guide and get an accurate result, for example, due to having no lower case characters.

Every font I have found that looks like it could be the right one, doesn't seem to be exactly the same. I narrowed it down to being Galba MN, at first. But the font is not quite the same. There are subtle differences. It may be just a case of the image file of the logo that I have, not being of high enough quality to use to identify on font identifier sites.

The font is part of a logo sent to me by a client whom I'm doing some work for. The logo was not designed by me and whomever did design the logo did not supply my client with any files that contain information on which font it is. My client thinks the font is Comfortaa, which it's obviously not.

I also need to find a good pairing for this font for a project and not sure yet, what would work well with it.

If anyone is familiar with the font in the image, I would appreciate you letting me know, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to a screenshot taken by @Wikimandia last year, this is Trajan Pro Bold (which I too believe is correct).

[image: Font comparison]

The first is your own sample, the second is your sample overlayed with Trajan Pro Bold, and the third is just Trajan Pro Bold that was used in the overlay.

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply. Thanks for your help, previously.

Answer (score 1):

[La Gioconda](https://www.youworkforthem.com/font/T2348/la-gioconda/typetester/) via Youworkforthem.com

[image: GIOCONDA NORMAL]
[image: GIOCONDA BOLD]